# I can't save specific file name using SaveFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, savefiledialog

I can't save a file for example with name: `ZK 10/2014`. I noticed that a problem is with this sign: `/`. Why is that? Maybe it's from the other reason?

Here is my code:

```
       Using SaveFileDialog1
            With SaveFileDialog1
                .Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*"
                .Title = "Save a file as"
                .FileName = "Default1"
            End With

            Try
                If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    path = IO.Path.GetFullPath(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
                End If

                If path <> "" Then
                    'Here I save a file using webservice's method'
                End If

            Catch ex As DirectoryNotFoundException
                Logi.LogInfo(ex)
            Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
                Logi.LogInfo(ex)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Logi.LogInfo(ex)
            End Try
        End Using
```

When I set a file name to `ZK 10/2014` I get MessageBox with this - *File name is invalid*. I want to use this name but I don't know what to change.

Comment: use a dash instead `ZK 10-2014` certain characters are simply illegal in file names like *, ?, \ etc

Comment: So there is no chance to use `/` ?

Comment: A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
`\ / : * ? " < > |` see http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/177506

Comment: No chance - the file system does not allow < > \ / : ? * or quote character.  Open explorer and try to rename a file to that format.  Illegal since 1979

Comment: You should now answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to @Plutonix's and @Matt Wilko's comments filename cannot contain characters like: `< > \ / | : * ? "`

As @Matt Wilko said, here it is described - http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/177506